# Problems with adding variants together VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA programming and how the different data types work, so I am running into a problem. I am adding two different numbers (`rng` and `rng1`) in an inputbox. If the user presses cancel the program closes down and the sheet locks. If I use e.g. an integer instead of a variant I can't run the close down code. However, when I try do `rng + rng1` it does not add them, but instead glues them together, i.e. if `grp = 2` and `grp1 = 3` then `grp + grp1 = 23`. This messes with my plot function. So I am hoping that someone can help me figure out the correct data types to use? Or a different solution to the problem. The code can be seen below.

```
dim grp As variant
dim grp1 As variant

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
grp = InputBox("Enter No in Group 1")
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If grp = "" Then
    MsgBox ("User canceled!")
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="..."
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
grp1 = InputBox("Enter No in Group 2")
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If grp1 = "" Then
    MsgBox ("User canceled!")
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="..."
    Exit Sub
End If

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate

With ActiveChart
    I = 3
    Do Until I = grp + 3
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(I).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(I).Select
        With Selection
            .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Border.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End With
        I = I + 1
    Loop

    j = grp + 3
    Do Until j = grp + grp1 + 3
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Select
        With Selection
            .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End With
        j = j + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: Newbie error:
-> On Error Resume Next - Never use that unless you are 100% sure what you are doing!
Remove all such and VBA will inform you what went wrong.

Comment: Hi peakpeak, I tried removing it but it gave me the exact same error as before (Do until will Count way out of range due to the add problem).

Comment: To add two *range* variables together, you need to access their *.Value* property, like so: `rng.Value + rng1.Value`

Comment: Note, however, that you are not using actual *range* variables, you are getting their values from an InputBox, which returns a *String* type variable.  You'll need to convert to numeric in order for the addition to work, like so: `CDbl(rng) + CDbl(rng1)`

Comment: Don't use `Variant` when a more appropriate type is available. If you're reading a `String`, store it in a `String` variable, not a `Variant`. Also, try to avoid Hungarian notation, *especially* if the prefixes you're using are actually completely misleading with regards to the type involved - one would typically expect `rngSomething` to be a `Range` object variable.

Comment: I agree with @Mat'sMug regarding variable naming and typing.  What you have is very confusing and difficult to work with.  This is easily remedied, but I have a quick question.  Will there ever be a time when `0` is an acceptable input from the user for either value?

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry for the confusion, tried correcting it in the example to not confuse future readers. I tried using string instead of variant which did not change the outcome. No I will probably have to make a close sub remark when 0 is the input (thanks for that input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it does not add them, but instead glues them together, i.e. if `grp = 2` and `grp1 = 3` then `grp + grp1 = 23`

`InputBox` returns a `String` type. What a lot of people don't realize is that you can use *either* the `&` or the `+` operator to combine strings, and that's what you're doing:

```
"2" + "3" = "23" '// equivalent to "2" & "3"
```

Whereas:

```
2 + 3 = 5
```

So because your parameters are of type `String`, the `+` operator assumes that you're trying to combine them, there's no implicit type conversion to `Int` or `Long` or `Double`, because the operator is perfectly valid for combining strings, which is what you gave it :)

***NOTE:*** It's usually recommended to *only* use the `&` operator, that way it's less ambiguous that you're combining strings, versus adding long/integer values.

**To handle the resulting input *as a numeric type*** (i.e., to perform *addition* or other arithmetic operation), then you need to be working with numeric data (`Integer/Long/Double` type) instead of `String` type. You could do an explicit typecast like:

```
Dim grp as Long
grp = CLng(InputBox("Enter No in Group 1"))
```

Or, more preferably, [use the `Type` argument of the `InputBox` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel):

```
Dim grp as Long
grp = InputBox("Enter No in Group 1", Type:=1)
```

Same for `grp2`.

Answer (score 1):

Because neither input can be 0, this will work for you just fine:

```
Dim dInput1 As Double
Dim dInput2 As Double

'Use Application.InputBox with Type 1 to force a numeric entry
dInput1 = Application.InputBox("Enter No in Group 1", Type:=1)
If dInput1 = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

'Use Application.InputBox with Type 1 to force a numeric entry    
dInput2 = Application.InputBox("Enter No in Group 2", Type:=1)
If dInput2 = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

'A simple example showing the values and their sum
MsgBox dInput1 & " + " & dInput2 & " = " & dInput1 + dInput2
```

Here's a link for more information regarding [Application.InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel)

Comment: This is great, much more elegant solution to the input thing...thanks so much