# How to place IF statement in next available column in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to place an IF statement in the next available column(dynamic) in row 2. Once the IF statement is in that cell, I want to add in the value from the last used row(dynamic) from that same column. I have been having trouble coding the IF statement into VBA. I also need help with coding it so it adds in the last row from the column into the cell with the IF statement. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub vlookupF5()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet

Dim NextColumn As Long
Dim ColumnStr As String
Dim ColumnStr2 As String
Dim ColumnStr3 As String
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Actuals")
Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
With sourceSheet
    SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With outputSheet
    NextColumn = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    If NextColumn + 1 < 27 Then
        ColumnStr = Chr(64 + NextColumn + 1)
    Else
        ColumnStr = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn + 1) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn + 1) Mod 26))
    End If
    If NextColumn - 1 < 27 Then
        ColumnStr3 = Chr(64 + NextColumn - 1)
    Else
        ColumnStr3 = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn - 1) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn - 1) Mod 26))
    End If
    If NextColumn < 27 Then
        ColumnStr2 = Chr(64 + NextColumn)
    Else
        ColumnStr2 = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn) Mod 26))
    End If
    OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Worksheets("Pivot").Activate
    .Range(Cells(2, NextColumn), .Cells(2, NextColumn)).Formula = _
    "=IF(R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R133C22,IF(R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C600),IF(R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C24),IF(R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C25),IF(R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C26),IF(R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C27),IF(R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C28),IF(R3C5=""sep"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C29),IF(R3C5=""Oct"",SUM" & _
                                                                  "!R133C22:R133C30),IF(R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C31),IF(R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C32),"""")))))))))))" * .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)
End With
End Sub
```

I keep getting

> "Error 13: Type Mismatch"

for this line:

```
"=IF(R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R133C22,IF(R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C600),IF(R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C24),IF(R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C25),IF(R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C26),IF(R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C27),IF(R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C28),IF(R3C5=""sep"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C29),IF(R3C5=""Oct"",SUM" & _
            "!R133C22:R133C30),IF(R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C31),IF(R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C32),"""")))))))))))" + .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes around your months instead of double quotes? Doing it the way you are doing it will cause VBA to think that `Feb` is some sort of variable that is not concatenated correctly.

Comment: Can you detail how your script is not working as expected?

Comment: @nbayly I've updated the question. I get error 13: type mismatch when I try to put the if function in

Comment: like this.... `"=IF(R3C5='Feb',A`

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes in your formula with another set of double quotes. E.g. `SomeCell.Formula = "=IF$E$3=""Feb"",RestOfFormulaHere"`

Comment: You're trying to *multiply* a string literal, that won't work.

Comment: @DavidZemens sorry I am still new to vba and don't know what that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a numeric value to a a string literal, that won't work:

```
.Range(Cells(2, NextColumn), .Cells(2, NextColumn)).Formula = _
    "=IF(R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R133C22,IF(R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C600),IF(R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C24),IF(R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C25),IF(R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C26),IF(R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C27),IF(R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C28),IF(R3C5=""sep"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C29),IF(R3C5=""Oct"",SUM" & _
                                                                  "!R133C22:R133C30),IF(R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C31),IF(R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C32),"""")))))))))))" + .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)
```

Let's break this down:

```
Dim sLongFormula$
sLongFormula = "=IF(R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R133C22,IF(R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C600),IF(R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C24),IF(R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C25),IF(R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C26),IF(R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C27),IF(R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C28),IF(R3C5=""sep"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C29),IF(R3C5=""Oct"",SUM" & _
                                                                  "!R133C22:R133C30),IF(R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C31),IF(R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C32),"""")))))))))))"
```

So what you end up with is:

```
.Range(Cells(2, NextColumn), .Cells(2, NextColumn)).Formula = sLongFormula  + .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)
```

[You simply can't add numeric values to a string in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572454/problems-with-adding-variants-together-vba/45573157#45573157) (using the `&` concatenator instead of the `+` would do an implicit type-conversion of numeric => string, however).

What you really need, I think:

```
.Range(.Cells(2, NextColumn), .Cells(2, NextColumn)).Formula = _
    sLongFormula & "+" & .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)
```

Note the addition of a leading `.` in `.Cells(2, NextColumn)` Previously, you would get a 1004 because you just Activated the pivot sheet, but you're defining a range inside a `With` block, and it is not possible to construct a range that includes cells spanning multiple worksheets.

__

Your formula looks suspect, if you break it down with more line breaks, you have:

```
sLongFormula = "=IF(R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R133C22,
            IF(R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C600), _
            IF(R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C24), _
            IF(R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C25), _
            IF(R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C26), _
            IF(R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C27), _
            IF(R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C28), _
            IF(R3C5=""sep"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C29), _
            IF(R3C5=""Oct"",SUM" & _
                                    "!R133C22:R133C30), _
            IF(R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C31), _
            IF(R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C32), _
            """")))))))))))"
```

So you're missing an opening parens and the `Actuals` for the `Oct` condition:

```
sLongFormula = "=IF(R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R133C22,
            IF(R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C600), _
            IF(R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C24), _
            IF(R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C25), _
            IF(R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C26), _
            IF(R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C27), _
            IF(R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C28), _
            IF(R3C5=""sep"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C29), _
            IF(R3C5=""Oct"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C30), _
            IF(R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C31), _
            IF(R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R133C22:R133C32), _
            """")))))))))))"
```

I also notice that March is C600, but all the other months are indexed from 24, etc. And strangely, February is not a `Sum` function at all. Both of these quirks might be *correct* for your usage, but they *appear* to me inconsistent.

You can probably simplify that monstrous function using some sort of lookup or `SumIf`/`SumIfs` function, too.

Comment: I actually didn't mean to put a *, I changed that to a plus sign. I am trying to add the value in the last used row of that column to the cell with the if function.

Comment: Like this? `....Formula = sLongFormula & "+" & .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)`

Comment: Yes exactly like that... Assuming the if statement is correct, which is the other thing I was having trouble with.

Comment: Note you can probably also simplify that longass formula with some sort of index/match/lookup or maybe SumIf/SumIfs .

Comment: I can't possibly help you with the `If` function. You should figure that out on the worksheet itself, and once you have it working (manually), then move it in to your VBA code :)

Comment: How on earth do you expect me to do that? Note you're missing an "Actuals" and a parenthesis in the "OCT" if branch.

Comment: when I ran your code I got: "Run-time Error 1004: Application defined or object defined error" for `.Range(Cells(2, NextColumn), .Cells(2, NextColumn)).Formula = _
    sLongFormula & "+" & .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)`

Comment: You mean when you ran *your* code :)  make sure all of your `Cells` are properly qualified, at least one of them appears to be missing a leading `.` which will possibly result in an illegaly-defined range (a range cannot consist of cells spanning multiple worksheets) and that will raise a 1004 EVERY TIME.

Comment: 1004 will also raise if the formula itself can't be evaluated, which may be the case if you haven't fixed some of the errors I mentioned.